# Export war from headless Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, eclipse-wtp

How do I export a WAR file from an Eclipse .web project programmatically with Java?

I have big problems with *war* ant task due to complex project structure(
ProjectX.web has a dependency from ProjectX.java) and i'm very confused by the 
*WebComponentExportWizard* implementation.

Is there any WTP API to use? (like this old version http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/j2ee/api/j2ee_operationsAPI.html )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some heavy fight i manage to obtain the war file trough this method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public static void exportWar(IProject webProject) throws CoreException {
    WebComponentExportDataModelProvider modelProvider = new WebComponentExportDataModelProvider();

    IDataModel dataModel = DataModelFactory.createDataModel(modelProvider);
    dataModel.setBooleanProperty(IJ2EEComponentExportDataModelProperties.EXPORT_SOURCE_FILES, false);
    dataModel.setBooleanProperty(IJ2EEComponentExportDataModelProperties.OVERWRITE_EXISTING, true);
    dataModel.setStringProperty(IJ2EEComponentExportDataModelProperties.PROJECT_NAME, webProject.getName());

    dataModel.setStringProperty(IJ2EEComponentExportDataModelProperties.ARCHIVE_DESTINATION, webProject
            .getLocation().append(webProject.getName()).addFileExtension("war").toOSString());
    dataModel.setProperty(
            IJ2EEComponentExportDataModelProperties.COMPONENT,
            ComponentCore.createComponent(webProject));

    IDataModelOperation modelOperation = dataModel.getDefaultOperation();
    try {
        log.debug("Start  the export war operation");
        modelOperation.execute(null, null);
    }
    catch (ExecutionException e) {
        log.error("Error when exporting .war project", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ilie Daniel Stefan, could you put somewhere all the necessary jars for download you have for this? I'm trying to do this with your code, but I cannot import necessary library from Eclipse. Seems Eclipse has different jars now, I cannot get it to work.

Comment: I don't have the sources of this project anymore. This is a very old problem (~5 years ago) so is somehow expected to have internal changes in the current Eclipse versions

Answer (score 0):

I used `org.eclipse.wst.server.core.util.PublishHelper.publishZip()` like below, and it works for me.

```java
IPath war = workDirectory.append("app.war");
PublishHelper publishHelper = new PublishHelper(null);
J2EEFlexProjDeployable deployable =
        new J2EEFlexProjDeployable(project, ComponentCore.createComponent(project));
publishHelper.publishZip(deployable.members(), war, null);
```

Comment: Hi, I don't know wether we are discussing the same thing or not. I trying to generate war file without eclipse, I have multiple projects that are need to be included in single war file.